# Seeing stats of Bitcoin website with 100 rep

Tags: discussion, beta-phase, site-stats

When I check posts on the Bitcoin Stack Exchange site I see the statistics of the site. I do not see these statistics on other SE sites though. But I think one must have a privilege to see these stats (5000 rep and over?) Is this a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a bug, and it's not the analytics page you are confusing this sidebar with. It's just the beta stats (i.e. appear only for beta sites), and they're public for anyone.

Comment: You're too fast!

Comment: Thank you. But then why I do not see these stats on any other website?

Comment: @Ber "appear only for beta sites"

Comment: @Begueradj http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic gives the same stats for all sites, graduated and beta.

Comment: And worth to mention, [list of all sites currently in beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta). /cc @Begueradj

Comment: @wythagoras thank you for the link